# Coded UI checkbox check

Tags: c#, user-interface, coded-ui-tests

I am trying to check two checkboxes in a web page using coded UI tool (C#) using the below code snippet.

```
HtmlCheckBox chkVeh = new HtmlCheckBox(BrowserInstance);
chkVeh.SearchProperties.Add(HtmlCheckBox.PropertyNames.Name, "checkbox1");
chkVeh.SearchProperties.Add(HtmlCheckBox.PropertyNames.Value, "Option1");                    
chkVeh.Checked = true;                   

HtmlCheckBox chkVeh1 = new HtmlCheckBox(BrowserInstance);
chkVeh1.SearchProperties.Add(HtmlCheckBox.PropertyNames.Name, "checkbox1");
chkVeh1.SearchProperties.Add(HtmlCheckBox.PropertyNames.Value, "Option2");                   
chkVeh1.Checked = true;
```

When I execute it. It checks the desired checkbox, but somehow just before moving to next step, it clicks on the checkbox again and unchecks the checkbox. At the end I'm left with 2 unchecked checkboxes.

eg.Checkbox1 checked
checkbox1 unchecked
Checkbox2 checked
Checkbox2 unchecked

I'm using Visual studio 2012.
Any pointers for this behaviour?

Comment: Do you mean it checks them when the page opens and then when the user wants to continue to the next page it unchecks them?

Comment: It checks the checkbox1, unchecks checkbox1, checks checkbox2 and unchecks checkbox2, all happening in same page. nothing to dod with navigation.

Comment: Outside CodedUI are you able to check those Checkbox?

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that the checkboxes have other code that only let them be checked via clicking on them, or interacting with them in the way a user would (not by changing a property directly). If the boxes can be clicked, try to use:

```
chkVeh.EnsureClickable();
Mouse.Click(chkVeh);
```

and see if that solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

i have a suggestion perform following steps:

1. record this check box action with recorder
2. Save this function
3. got to defination of method 
   [image]
4. go to defination of control properties
   [image]
5. Copy Whole generated class generated against recording 
   [image]
6. Paste code in word use the filter and search parameter used here in your hand coded script it makes easy to identify parameters needed by Coded UI Script 
   [image]

   10. I have a usage example too see the one 
       [image]

Comment: Its really long and difficult to understand the answer